# Python - Selenium Web Driver - can't find xpath for "edit images" button on craigslist

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use the following code to click on the "Edit Images" button on craigslist

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/form/input[@value='Edit Images']").click()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //form/input[@value='Edit Images']
```

The following is the source code for the craigslist page that I am working with. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

[image]

Comment: Cause it's a button, not an input...

Comment: okay, now I am getting a similar error    Unable to locate element: /form/button[@value='Edit Images']

Comment: got it! I had one slash at the beginning of my xpath instead of two

Answer (score 0):

try xpath

//button[@value = 'Edit Images']

but you have to make sure that this element is visible.